# Win8 C# Metro dispatcher and RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to build an application using the unofficial Google music api for .net in Windows 8 metro interface.
I am loading the whole playlist

```
foreach (GoogleMusicPlaylist p in pls.UserPlaylists)
                lbPlaylists.Items.Add(p.Title);
```

and it comes up with this error

```
HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
```

And I read around the internet and maybe I have to use dispatcher or something I am just generally confused.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to access the UI from any other thread than the UI-thread? :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Yes you can see he is adding an item to a UIElement directly (this is not considered good practice, by the way). I think he likely just needs to use Dispatcher Invoke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                foreach (GoogleMusicPlaylist p in pls.UserPlaylists)
                {
                    lbPlaylists.Items.Add(p.Title);
                }
            });
```