# MessageDialog - needs to wait for user input

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await, messagedialog

I have a ViewModel which instantiates an event in a synchronous method.  The event signals to the UI that we need a "Yes" or "No" answer from the user before continuing.

I am trying to display a `MessageDialog` and wait until the user provides an answer - Yes or No.  I am having a difficult time doing this.  I currently get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when trying to do this.

Here's a look at the code in the UI:

```
async Task<bool> Instance_SwitchConfirmation(string question)
{
    MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(question);
    md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", CommandInvokedHandler));
    md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", CommandInvokedHandler));
    md.ShowAsync();

    return this.canSwitch;
}

async void CommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{
    this.canSwitch = command.Label == "Yes" ? true : false;
}
```

I have tried:

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(question);
    md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", CommandInvokedHandler));
    md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", CommandInvokedHandler));
    md.ShowAsync();
}, 
new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), 
TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, uiContext);
```

but this fails with the same exception.

Lastly, if I simply await the MessageDialog like so, the dialog is not displayed and the UI thread locks up.

```
MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(question);
md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", CommandInvokedHandler));
md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", CommandInvokedHandler));
await md.ShowAsync();
```

If `MessageDialog` had a synchronous version of `Show()` I would be fine but the asynchrnous behvaior of `MessageDialog` coupled with my synchrounous routine, coupled with cross threading is confusing me.  I'm wondering if someone can outline what I need to do to wait for user input on a `MessageDialog` before continuing a synchronous method in my backend ViewModel.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Win8 C# Metro dispatcher and RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822392/win8-c-sharp-metro-dispatcher-and-rpc-e-wrong-thread) and [`CoreDispatcher.RunAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync).

Since your method isn't executing on the `Dispatcher` you're going to need to invoke the code on it manually. In order to avoid refactoring into a callback pattern you can use a [`TaskCompletionSource(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) to set the result and the background thread will continue after the result is set.

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
var dialogTask = tcs.Task;

MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(question);
md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
md.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No"));

Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => {
    var result = await md.ShowAsync();
    var canSwitch = result.Label == "Yes";
    tcs.SetResult(canSwitch);
});

var result = await dialogTask;
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to await the user input before I can continue code execution.  If I await the Dispather.RunAsync call, the MessageDialog is not displayed and the UI thread locks up.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response.  Unfortunately, this still isn't awaiting, I have a return canSwitch; statement after this call and its being called prior to showing the MessageDialog, if I await the Dispatcher.RunAsync call I again have the UI thread locked.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: What you can probably do is use a `TaskCompletionSource(T)` to let the `Dispatcher` run. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response, but this also does not display my MessageDialog and locks the UI thread...

Comment: Something else interesting, if I call your code above from the initialization of the UI class, this behaves as expected.  But when called in the UI event handler that's run after I raise an event in my backend ViewModel (in a different assembly) - I get the locked behavior.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you might be calling `Wait` somewhere which is blocking the UI. Make sure all of your code is using the async pattern.

Comment: So how was this solved? This answered is marked correct, but the solution doesn't work for me with the same problems as @user2334154 is mentioning.